# Android WebView Async Call to Java Function

Tags: javascript, java, android, asynchronous, webview

I'm looking for a way to make async calls to Android's native code from JS

I have a Main Activity with the following code to make accessible native code to JS:

```
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new BindingHelper(this), "Android");
 webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

The BindingHelper Class contains something like this:

```
 @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(theContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

 @JavascriptInterface
        public String SuperDuperComplexFunction () {
            //A function that will need some time to finish...
            return "{}";
        }
```

The previous Methods can be called from the Index.html linked JS as follows:

```
<script type="text/js">
  Android.showToast("Toast");
</script>
```

In that way the `showToast()` function is executed synchronously. What I need is to call the method `SuperDuperComplexFunction();` in a aSync way (just like an AJAX Request), and when the method **success** take some action.
Any ideas?

Comment: `mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:" + script)` and `mWebView.evaluateJavascript(script, null);` depends on API level ...

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816325/asynchronous-javascript-calls-from-android-webview/30826012#30826012

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an Http Server in java code and then make the AJAX call on localhost. That way the Javascript call would be the exact same as any other AJAX call, and since you control the Http Server you can just have it call your `SuperDuperComplexFunction()`

I've used [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) in the past for something kind of similar but not quite the same.